# Is there an opposite of :g in vim?

Tags: vim, regex

I know how to do something to every line that matches a pattern, using `:g`.  Is there a way to do something to every line that does *not* match the pattern?

For example, suppose I want to delete every line that does not match /foo/.  I might do something like:

```
:G/foo/d
```

(`:G` is not the opposite of `:g`, but that is what I am looking for)

Any ideas?

Comment: miv ni g:        .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think there is a inversion within VIM as,

```
:g!/foo/d
```

or, like the `grep` command (below),

```
:v/foo/d
```

---

If you are ready to go to the shell prompt,

```
grep -v foo filename.txt > new.txt
```

will do this